# Spring profiles configuration

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot

I have a profile called "stage", I am trying to implement a web service but whenever I make a request I get some error, whenever I delete the profile annotation it works normally, I dont really know why it is not working with a profile here are some classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
          context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("stage");
          context.register(MyApp.class);    
          SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);

    }

}
@Profile("stage")
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:jdbc.properties" })
public class StageDSConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String jdbcURL;
    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(jdbcURL);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(createDatabasePopulator(), dataSource);
        return dataSource;
    }

    private DatabasePopulator createDatabasePopulator() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(true);
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("schema-mysql.sql"));
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("data-mysql.sql"));
        return databasePopulator;
    }
}
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "ws")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultActionWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema actionSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ActionPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.example.com/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(actionSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema wsSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("ws.xsd"));
    }

}
```

and this is the error log:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO logs(ipAddress,actionn,requestBody) values(?,?,?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: LOGS</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are not correctly activating the profile. With springBoot, you may set the profile like this:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(MyApp.class).profiles("stage").run(args);
```

Or, through an environment variable:

```
System.setProperty(AbstractEnvironment.ACTIVE_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "stage");
SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
```

Comment: yes thank you that was the problem, I was not activating the profile correctly

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you don't actually activate the "stage" profile, so the context is missing all the beans in StageDSConfig class and thus no schema is created